# How do I clear local calendar events cache and re-sync?

Tags: 20.04, calendar, nextcloud, gnome-calendar

I recently started using a Nextcloud instance for my calendar events. I am able to sync events so they show up in the GNOME Calendar app, but there are many duplicates. Is there some place where events are cached locally where I can examine them or clean them up?

The events display properly in the Nextcloud Calendar app -- I don't see any duplicates. I only see the duplicates in GNOME Calendar.

I looked in locations mentioned in [In what file does gnome-calendar store calendar events?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1272730/in-what-file-does-gnome-calendar-store-calendar-events) but I didn't see any actual calendar event data, just references to the calendar webdav URIs.

I tried deleting and re-adding my Nextcloud account in the "Online Accounts" settings dialog. I tried disabling and re-enabling Calendar synchronization for my Nextcloud account.

I'm using:

- Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
- Nextcloud 19.0.3 (latest stable)
- GNOME Calendar 3.36.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like they are in SQLite3 databases under `~/.cache/evolution/calendar/`. I was able to trash that directory and it automatically re-sync'd. Yay!

The duplicates still exist; this separate issue might be with the Nextcloud database. I downloaded the ics file for the calendar from Nextcloud and I do see what appear to be duplicates in there.

Comment: I was having trouble with a related issue (recurring events that kept appearing after they were edited to add an end date) and found that I had to kill the calendar first. I did `pkill -f calendar` to stop the calendar and then `rm -rf ~/{.local/share,.cache}/evolution/calendar/` to get any mystery caches cleared.

Comment: Yeah, a better method to kill the calendar is shown in @francois-corthay's answer

Comment: Good to know. If that one gets upvoted past this one I'll mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Hrm. Now I can't get any combination of this and the other answer to get my ubuntu 22.04 LTS desktop GNOME calendar syncing with Nextcloud calendar again. Anyone else have more luck? I also asked here: https://help.nextcloud.com/t/how-to-delete-and-re-sync-gnome-calendar-tasks-contacts/153617

Answer (score 3):

Quit all *evolution* items (see `ps ax | grep evolution`):

```
evolution --force-shutdown
```

and clear cache:

```
evolution --force-shutdown
```

Restarting *evolution* will show how the appointments are loaded back into the calendar.

Comment: This first, then the answer by @adam-monsen did the trick!

Comment: @francois-corthay are those two code sections in your answer supposed to be different? I think some other command is necessary to clear the cache. I'm also curious if this works on Ubuntu 22.04 or if some other solution is necessary.